# Z-test in excel without input array

Tags: probability, statistics

100 taxi drivers took a shot of vodka. Their reaction time was measured before and after. Giving us following data:

- BEFORE | Mean: 0.4 and s^2: 0.0005
- AFTER | Mean: 0.44 and s^2: 0.0006

Can I rule out with 0.01 probability that taking a shot of vodka doesn't affect reaction time?

I am allowed to use excel, but I can't figure out how to solve this task, because z-test in excel takes in an array of data, but in my case only the mean of sample is given.

Comment: You are given the standard deviation as well.  The question as stated doesn't make sense because you can never conclude it does not affect reaction time.  You may be able to rule out that it does not affect reaction time.

Comment: @RossMillikan it actually _does_ ask me to rule out that it does not affect reaction time

Comment: Roughly speaking, you want to find the standard deviations from the $s^2$ values you have.  If the difference in the means is more than a couple standard deviations, you can exclude the null hypothesis.  What is the standard deviation of the difference of the means?  You shouldn't need Excel, just your tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A paired t test is essentially a one-sample test on the $n$
differences. Let $U_i$ be the reaction time before and $U_2$ be
the reaction time after. Then the increased reaction time for the
$i$th driver is $D_i = U_2 - U_1.$

The t statistic for testing $H_0:\mu_A - \mu_B = 0$
against $H_a; \mu_A-\mu_B \ne 0$ is $T = \frac{\bar D - 0}{S_D/\sqrt{n}},$
where $S_D$ is the standard deviation of the differences $D_i.$
If reaction times are roughly distributed as normal, then $T$ is
approximately distributed as Student's t distribution with $n-1$
degrees of freedom.

You know that $\bar D = \bar U_2 - \bar U_1.$ 
However, from what you are given, you can't know $S_D$ exactly, because before and after reaction times for the same driver are *not* independent. But probably $S_D^2 \le S_1^2 + S_2^2 = S_T^2;$ it seems reasonable that the $U_1$ and $U_2$ are positively correlated. So you
might use $S_D \approx S_T$ as a worst-case scenario in computing the statistic $T$.

I will leave it to you to finish this.